# Asset folder 404 error on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

So basically I made an e-portfolio using create-react-app and when i used the github pages link (eyoo217.github.io/e-portfolio), the website loaded perfectly fine. However I got a new domain (elotmusk.com) and now the assets cant be loaded to the domain?

Github link to repo: https://github.com/eyoo217/e-portfolio

Package.json link: https://github.com/eyoo217/e-portfolio/blob/main/package.json

I changed the homepage link in the json file to match the new url but still not working.